# Can WebSocket be an alternative to a Java applet?

Tags: javascript, java, websocket, applet

Is it possible use the WebSocket API of JavaScript, to communicate with a native application, on the client side, like an alternative to an applet, which have to access to the file system?

I will communicate with the client side by ws://localhost:xxxx, but I don't know if I could do it.

And If I could, this will be secure. Will I have to take some security considerations?

Comment: WebSocket is just communication protocol between client and server. It can be secured if initiated using https. it cant be used to communicate to native application in client side.

Comment: but I saw an example here [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm). Maybe you want say I musn't but I can; or I am in a mistake.

Comment: That link shows how to open a websocket connection through javascript. That's 50% of your requirement and is indeed possible. And the other half?

Comment: I suppose that I could create an server application that run on the client machine, and listen the port xxxx of my web application's localhost... but I am not sure... In the new server(client side), I will access to the file system and return it to the web app by the WebSocket too.  If I am wrong, Why can I not?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is more: how do you get the server onto the client and the client configured so connections can be made? Its easy to do on your own local development machine, sure. But think about a realistic scenario.

Comment: I will install a native application(server in the client), then the client must execute the app and after this he could access to the web, so the connections would be made by the port xxxx. The native application knows that it must listen by the localhost of this port, so I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not install a WebSocket server on a user's machine to replace the functionality of accessing the local filesystem in the same way that Java applets would.

Not without the user actively installing the WebSocket server on their own machine intentionally.

Your biggest problem is that the Javascript client code does not have unrestricted access to the user's filesystem.  This is a security feature.  This is an *important* security feature.  You can not place arbitrary files on the user's machine in arbitrary places.

After that, Javascript client code also can not start processes on your system, even if it could get a WebSocket server installed in an arbitrary location.  Again, this is a *critical* security feature.

And finally, if your Javascript client code *could* install and execute arbitrary software on the user's machine, you wouldn't need a WebSocket server for the use case you're looking for right now.

---

If you were to convince a user to install a WebSocket server on their own machine for your use case, which is to access the user's local filesystem, then you would have major security concerns to take into consideration.  Not all filesystems have user and group based read/write/execute permissions... and even then, the user might start the server from within a privileged account.

The browser is designed to implicitly trust the server that it's attached to as far as whatever Javascript it receives.  If your user later browses a malicious site which knows about your locally installed WebSocket server, and what commands it might expect, the browser will quite happily allow the malicious server to send any commands to your user's WebSocket server that they wish.

With my strong personal recommendation to respect the sanctity of the user's filesystem and obey the restrictions that browsers place on Javascript clients access to the local machine, if you do decide to try to convince your users to install a local WebSocket server, you must take absolute care to be as security conscious as possible.  Validate **all** input, regardless of whether you think an attacker can't possibly generate it, and never blacklist known risks, ONLY whitelist known safe functions.

Remember, if you do anything to expose the user's filesystem to the web, you are pretty much handing the keys to their computer over to anyone who can find the door.